# json parsing exception in postman environment variables

Tags: postman

I am trying to chain my rest apis in postman.After one of the api gets executed i saved 2 variables in environment using:

```
 postman.setEnvironmentVariables("x","xValue");
 postman.setEnvironmentVariables("y","yValue");
```

Now i need these 2 variable to be passed as json in next api. I am passing this as follows:

[image]

But values are not getting passed not as expected.Values is still being passed as "{{xValue}}" instead of some Value.

Can somebody help if i am doing something wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an undefined variable `{{xValue}}` inside your request body, that is why it's just returning this string. If you change it to `{{x}}` --> you will get the output `xValue`.

For example:

```
// set environment variable named "variable_key"
pm.environment.set("variable_key", "variable_value");


// access environment variable named "variable_key" in your request body
{
  "someKey": {{variable_key}}
}
```

> **Postman Test Examples**
>
> https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples/